# qfilesystemwatcher emits directorychanged signal 2 times when file edited

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I need to watch a directory in qt. created the connection. but when file edited, the sender emits directory changed signal twice. filechanged signal also emitted at the same time. what is the use of emitting the signal twice? and is there any way to know which file/folder is changed? please help..
here is the connect code

```
QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher;
watcher->addPath("/home/user/directory/");
connect(watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(directoryChangedHandler(QString)));
```

and function

```
void MainWindow::directoryChangedHandler(QString path)
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Directory Changed", "Directory Changed at " + path);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code where you set up the connections

Comment: added the code. please check that and reply me.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only connect statement / the function it is in is not called twice?

Comment: ya sure. and I have one more connect statement which connects the filechanged signal to a slot. it calls one time only. tried commenting it.

Comment: @TimMeyer is that you who down voted for this question? If yes please undo that. I have updated the code right? I think there is no problem with the code. that's why I didn't included the code.

Comment: The downvote is not from me, unfortunately I cannot help you though, I fear. What you could do is finding all occurrences `emit directoryChanged` in the Qt Souce Code and debug through the code to find out why the signal is fired twice. I'll give you an upvote so you're back to 0, I see no problem with your question.

Comment: thanks for that. But I couldn't debug that. still it emits the signal twice. Will u please try the same code and check how many times the signal emits. me tried the same code in a windows PC too. got the problem there too..

Comment: Now I concluded that there is no issue with the code. Because, I tried the nano editor to edit the file, which returns no directoryChnaged signal. But it emits fileChanged signal. So other editors removes and writes the file again I think. That's why it emits directoryChnaged signal twice. and one more thing that I noted is, the path for the file is removed from the watcher while using the normal editors. Not while using nano. thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: I just added my conclusion as answer. please edit that if you found anything wrong or missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The normal editors removes and writes the file again from the disk. So two signals for deleted file and added file. I tried editing the file using `nano` editor in `Ubuntu`. It does not emits any `directoryChanged` signal but emits the `fileChanged` signal. So that means it does not removes and adds the file, but edits the same file. One more thing that helps this conclusion is, while using the normal editor, the path is removed from the `watcher`. That means, the file doesn't exist for a while. I have to add that path manually again. Which is not happening while using `nano`. Since I wrote the code to add the path again, it shows the error "`QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/user/directory/file`". Because the path is already in the `watcher`.